# Netlogo : inequality doesn't work properly under foreach

Tags: list, foreach, netlogo, inequality

It supposes to be a simple code, but I don't know why it doesn't work properly.
I want to change a  color of non-white turtle back into white if a condition is fulfilled. I put inequality as the condition.

for example, if the amount of red turtle > = 5, then [ do something ]. 
No error message for the code, but I found that [ do something ] codes are executed before the condition is fulfilled. For example, it is executed when the amount of turtle is 1 or 4. And I also found that there are moments when it reach > = 5, [ do something] code is not executed.

Below is the code

```
to seize-value
  ask consumers [set type-of-value ( list blue red green) ] 
  foreach type-of-value [
    if count consumers with [color = ?] > = 5 [ 
        let z consumers with [color = ?]
          ask z [ set color white ]
          ask consumers with [color = white] [set value? false]
          ask one-of cocreation-patches [ sprout 1 [gen-prevalue]]
    ]]
end
```

I've tried using a single color, instead of a list of color (without - foreach) it doesn't work either.

Can anyone help with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have something like the following at the top of your code to set up type-of-value as an agent variable:

```
breed [ consumers consumer ]
consumers-own [ type-of-value ]
```

However, you are treating it as a global variable in your code. First you say `ask consumers [set type-of-value ( list blue red green) ]` to set the AGENT variable called type-of-value to the list of colours. But you end that `ask []` statement before starting the `foreach`.

Unless the consumers have different lists of colours, what you really want is something more like this (untested). Note that I have also removed your multiple creations of the same agentset (for efficiency):

```
globals [ type-of-value ]

to setup
  clear-all
  ...
  set type-of-value ( list blue red green)
  ...
  reset-ticks
end

to seize-value
*type "seize-value on tick " print ticks
  foreach type-of-value
  [ let changers consumers with [color = ?]
*print ?
*print count changers
    if count changers >= 5
    [ ask changers
      [ set color white
        set value? false
      ]
      ask one-of cocreation-patches [ sprout 1 [gen-prevalue] ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

**UPDATE for debugging** I have added three lines that will output key information for debugging. They are marked with an asterisk (*). Add those lines (without the *) and look at the output.

Comment: I've tried your code, it works well for single color. Unfortunately it doesn't work well for list of color. I tried to remove equal sign "='' from the code, the result is better. However, for every 3 runs I found at least 1 runs inaccurate.

Comment: You really need to tell us what you mean by 'doesn't work well'. Is it producing an error? Is it doing something different than what you expect and, if so, what do you expect and what is it doing? I just realised that I had copied your code and missed the `> =` that should have been `>=` (no space). What do you mean by list of colors, what are you actually trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to change non white turtle into white turtle when their population reach 5 or more. For example, when red turtle population equal or more than 5, red turtle will change into white.  The problem with the code is sometimes netlogo executes [ set color ] when the population less than 5. The code it self producing no error, it just doesn't work as I expect to. And yes, i've removed the space between > and =. I would very appreciate your help. Thankyou

Comment: "sometimes netlogo executes [ set color ] when the population less than 5" – how do you know? by what means are you gathering and interpreting that information? perhaps the problem is actually there; I don't think there is any such problem in the code that JenB has provided.

Comment: At first, I thought so too. But when I observe using small population (10 turtles), run the simulation slower, monitor each turtle number and plot it to two graphs, I found the problem. I use two graphs to observe the turtle amount for each color and the other to observe patches breed new turtle when the condition is fulfilled. As I told you earlier, the code becomes accurate when I only use one color - without "foreach". I  kinda bit worried with this problem because in the next step I might need to use more turtle population with more colors. Any suggestion please? Thank you in advance

Comment: When you sprout a turtle, are you giving it a color? If so, then (for example) there might only be 3 red turtles at the start of the foreach, but 5 red turtles by the time 'red' is reached because 2 new red turtles have been sprouted. Where else in your code do you have turtles changing colour? Rather than do plots, put some print statements in your code so you can see if anything has an unexpected value. I will amend my code to demonstrate this.

Comment: The turtle sprouts different type of agent set. Agent set "consumer"  will sprout "prevalue". I use this code to sprout prevalue ( i am sorry for the bad formatting, still figuring out how to format code on comment section) :                                   to gen-prevalue
  set breed prevalues 
  set shape "circle"
  set color orange +  2
  set value random (4 - 1) + 1
  ask patch-here [ set resource random (4 - 1) + 1 ]
  set process-time 0
end

Comment: I have turtles changing color on two blocks. One from white to another color (my thread before this thread) and this block to change from another color into white. I'll try your tips to put some print statement. Thanks @JenB

Comment: I second the suggestion to add `print` statements. Adding `print` statements will allow you to observe what your code is actually doing at any level of detail you want. If you observe closely enough at a high enough level of detail, you will either find the problem yourself, or you will have the information you need to ask a new question.